# How to add an background image to the link of Github Pages?

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I uploaded my code to a repository in Github and use Github Pages to show my website on the Internet. But when I copy the link and paste it to somewhere like a messenger on Facebook, it doesn't show an image inside. How can I do that?

Here is my pic. How can I add an image inside this link?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include this in the head of the HTML code,

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">`

You can know more about this [here](https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/)

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue!

Comment: I did it. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad, it worked! Just to make sure it’s equally beneficial for other community members too, cloud you please mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add relevant meta tags for preview images for your pages.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="image url" />
```

Check this https://andrejgajdos.com/how-to-create-a-link-preview/